# anything vs. something/no one knows

Tags: negation

Can one say

a. No one knows something is wrong here.

b. No one knows anything is wrong here.

c. No one thinks something is wrong here.

d. No one thinks anything is wrong here.

e. Does anyone know that something is wrong here?

f. Does anyone know that anything is wrong here?

?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> a. No one knows something is wrong here.

Something: has the connotation that there is 'something' that **IS** wrong

> b. No one knows anything is wrong here.

Anything: it has the connotation that it **may or may not be** wrong, but no one knows it.

Most of the time, it depends on the context something/anything are being used. Usually, when you say something, it applies that it exists.

However, anything, generally, applies that it may or may not exists.

Again, it may vary on how they are used.